# How to use different TypeHandler for two different connection types

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a project which connects to two different database engines. One for MySql and one for MSSQL. I'm using dapper to map my queries to objects.

Now I run into a problem with my converting the types. In MySql a bool value is saved as `0` or `1`. In MSSQL a boolean is represented by `J` and `N`.

So whenever I'll use a connection using my MSSQL Handler, I'll need to use my custom TypeHandler for this connection.

```cs
public class TrendBooleanTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<bool>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, bool value)
    {
        parameter.Value = (value ? "J" : "N");
    }

    public override bool Parse(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return value.ToString() == "J";
    }
}
```

However, once this typehandler has been registered, the converting to boolean in my MySql connection will fail since it tries to convert the boolean now just like the MSSQL connection.

Is there any way to tell dapper to only use this typehandler when the request is being done via `SqlConnection` and not `MySqlConnection`?

Comment: You can combine them into one. You can check the `DbType` property of the `parameter` argument if it is a char then apply J N logic else apply bit logic. Other than that you have to control it by manually calling `ÀddTypeMap` and `RemoveTypeMap`